# Connect LocalDB to ASP.net Project

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2012, connection-string, localdb

I have as ASP.net project with localDB in it.
The database file name is ProjectDB.sdf and I placed him in the App_Data folder.

My connection string is:

```
<add name="ProjectConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\ProjectDB.sdf;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

I try to use the database in my cs file like this:

```
conn.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ProjectConnection"].ConnectionString;
using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
{
    cmd.CommandText = "select JobTitleId, JobTitleText from LuJobTitle where JobTitleText like @SearchText + '%'";
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SearchText", prefix);
    cmd.Connection = conn;
    conn.Open();
```

The application falls in the conn.Open(); command.

The error message I get says:

```
An attempt to attach an auto-named database for file d:\user\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\RealMatchSite\RealMatchSite\App_Data\ProjectDB.sdf failed.
A database with the same name exists, or specified file cannot be opened, or it is located on UNC share.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Check this thread: [An attempt to attach an auto-named database](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12566036/an-attempt-to-attach-an-auto-named-database-for-file-database1-mdf-failed)

Comment: Use SQL Server Express instead

Answer (score 0):

Your db server already has database attached with that name so you are getting that error. If this is not the case then try adding this to your connections string:

```
User Instance=True
```

Comment: When I added "User Instance=True" I got this: "The user instance login flag is not allowed when connecting to a user instance of SQL Server. The connection will be closed.". My db server is the local host. How do I remove all the databases from it and keep the only one I need?

Comment: Do you have sql mgmt studio? Login and remove it.

Answer (score 0):

Try using Initial Catalog to call your database.
I hope this helps.

connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=ProjectDB;Integrated Security=True"

Comment: I tried it and got this error message: "Cannot open database "ProjectDB" requested by the login. The login failed.

Login failed for user 'User-PC\User'."

Comment: Is your server password protected?? If so, include ConnString = "Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0; Initial Catalog = ProjectDB; Persist Security Info = True; User ID = user; Password =password";

Comment: It is currently using your machine credentials to access your database. The good news is it found the database and trying to access it.