# I am getting an error whenever I am saving the data to the SQL Server database using C#

Tags: c#, sql

I am working with my personal project which is a personal expenses system. I am trying to save data to SQL Server, but I am always getting an error:

> "0x80131904" an attempt to attach an auto name database. A database with the same name exists. or specified file cannot be opened or it is located on UNC share"

To give you the complete error I attached here.

Thanks.

```
try
{ 
    SqlConnection conn =  new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C: \Users\Francis\source\repos\Personal Expenses System\NumData.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30");

    conn.Open();

    string insert_query = "INSERT INTO [Table111] (House Rent, NB Power, Car Insurance, Life Insurance, Gasoline, Grocery, Rogers Internet, kodoo Mobile, Laundry, Tithes, Padala, Extra, Total, Gross Income, Net Income) VALUES (@House Rent, @NB Power, @Car Insurance, @Life Insurance, @Gasoline, @Grocery, @Rogers Internet, @kodoo Mobile, @Laundry, @Tithes, @Padala, @Extra, @Total, @Gross Income, @Net Income)";

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(insert_query, conn);

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@House Rent", textbox1.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NB Power", textBox2.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Car Insurance", textBox3.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Life Insurance", textBox4.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Gasoline", textBox5.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Grocery", textBox6.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Rogers Internet", textBox7.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@kodoo Mobile", textBox8.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Laundry", textBox9.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Tithes", textBox10.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Padala", textBox11.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Extra", textBox12.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Total", textBox13.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Gross Income", textBox14.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Net Income", textBox15.Text);

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    MessageBox.Show("Record SAVE");
    conn.Close();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show("EROR:" + ex.ToString());
}
```

I attached the screen shot of the error. It was lengthy one.

[image: ERROR]
[image: SQL]

Comment: If you Google for `an attempt to attach the auto named database failed` there are a number of suggestions. Can you update your question to make clear which of those suggestions you have already tried?

Comment: Also: make sure to post error messages as *text* not as an image. It is impossible for future visitors to find questions that solve they problems if errors/code is shown as image.

Comment: I guess the error was I  reported earlier was different error for what I attached here.

Comment: I attached the error as an image because it was  lengthy but I tried to put as a text the beginning error.

Comment: Any luck updating your question with the suggestions you've already tried?

Comment: **Side note:** `decimal(18,0)` as datatype seems odd - this means 18 digits, but **none** after the decimal point - so you're basically giving up on all cent values and can store only dollar amounts - is that what you wanted?? Otherwise change it to e.g. `decimal(18,2)` which means 18 digits in all, 2 of which after the decimal point, so you can store amounts with 2 digits after the decimal point

Answer (score 0):

The problem is probably happening because you're not defining a correct path for your database file NumData.mdf. Using your error message "an attempt to attach an auto named database for file" I found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12566036/an-attempt-to-attach-an-auto-named-database-for-file-database1-mdf-failed) here:)

Comment: This is not an answer, you can make it an answer by  using your own words and experience to describe the problem and solution and it is some how different to the duplicate you referenced

Comment: Thanks for the advise! I'll avoid answer while I cannot mark a question as duplicated.

Comment: I am pretty sure this is the correct path. I am using local sql database via visual studio 2017.

Comment: Not sure if I'm helpful at this time, but, I suggest you to try another search terms to find this answer here, for example "sql connection string mdf". I found this one based on your comment (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8926512/how-do-i-connect-to-an-mdf-database-file).

Comment: I copied the connection string of the database itself but still getting the error

Comment: If you're using locally on your computer you could try to attach the .mdf file to SQL Express and connect using a different connectionString.

Comment: I am trying to connect on the local sql which is built-in to visual studio 2017. I am not sure if I understand clearly your suggestion. would you be able to elaborate please. I am  new to programming. Thanks