# Get SQL Connection error while using Web Service with local SQL Server database

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis-express

I'm setting up a web service, I wanted to use the local database so I created a local SQL Server database in this project. The web service runs just fine on localhost, but the problem when I invoke a method to Load data from the local database on this project, I'm getting an error:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException:
>   An attempt to attach an auto-named database for file C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express\TourTravelDB.mdf failed. A database with the same name exists, or specified file cannot be opened, or it is located on UNC share.

`TourTravelDB.mdf` is my local database

I've added a connection string in my `web.config` but it's still not working.

Here is my connection string.

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="CS" 
         connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\TourTravelDB.mdf;Integrated Security=True" 
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

I've also tried to move my database to the IIS Express directory, it works but when run it from another computer, I have to move the database again.

Does anyone have an idea how to solve this?

Comment: Hi Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please take a look on this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12566036/an-attempt-to-attach-an-auto-named-database-for-file-database1-mdf-failed

Comment: Ali Bahrami thks for replying but it's stil not works for me, the error  in that post seems diffenrent from my error

Comment: What kind of project do you have? WebForms, MVC/WebAPi, ASPNetCore?

Comment: It's ASP.Net Web Application

Comment: Where do you save your `TourTravelDB.mdf` file? Is it in the app_data folder?

Answer (score 0):

This may help you..

Add "User Instance=True;" in your connection string.

```
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="aspnet_staterKits_Test_TimeTracker" 
         connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLExpress;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|aspnetdb.mdf;"/>
    <remove name="LocalSqlServer"/>
    <add name="LocalSqlServer"
         connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLExpress;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|aspnetdb.mdf;"/>
  </connectionStrings>
```

---

if doesn't work then try out the below links..

[forums.asp.net](https://forums.asp.net/t/879454.aspx?An%20attempt%20to%20attach%20an%20auto%20named%20database%20for%20file%20failed)

[codeproject.com](https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/192140/An-attempt-to-attach-an-auto-named-database-for-fi)

[Already existing thread in stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12566036/an-attempt-to-attach-an-auto-named-database-for-file-database1-mdf-failed)